# Implementing Hybrid Encryption?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric, hybrid

I already have an asymmetric algorithm implemented in an MVC C# Application, however I would like to modify the encryption method so that I make use of both symmetric and asymmetric encryption (AKA Hybrid encryption). Any idea how I can do this?

Asymmetric encrypt:

```
public string AsymmEncrypt(int accId, string input, string publickey)
    {
        Account a = new UserRepository().GetAccountById(accId);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider myAlg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
        publickey = new UserRepository().PublicKeyByAccountId(accId);
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = publickey;
        myAlg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

        byte[] cipher = myAlg.Encrypt(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input), true);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipher);
    }
```

Asymmetric decrypt:

```
        public string AsymmDecrypt(int accId, string input, string privatekey)
    {
        Account a = new UserRepository().GetAccountById(accId);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider myAlg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
        privatekey = new UserRepository().PrivateKeyByAccountId(accId);

        byte[] cipher = myAlg.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(input), true);
        return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipher);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use this for Symmetric key distribution?  Typically, you would use symmetric encryption for large amounts of data because it's faster, then encrypt the symmetric key asymmetrically for distribution.

Comment: When you run it on an https URL you get hybrid encryption done by experts.

Comment: There's an example of using RSA with AES in the MSDN documentation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsapkcs1keyexchangeformatter.aspx

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you are trying to encrypt with your custom method, and why hosting your MVC app within HTTPS isn't adequate.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not try to reinvent the wheel here.  The System.Security.Cryptography namespace in .net alrady provides a large array of cryptography functionality that is quite well vetted.  Don't try to use your own Asymmetric functions to accomplish this.

If you want to do private key distribution through public key encryption, you should use something like [RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsapkcs1keyexchangeformatter.aspx) or maybe even [RSAOAEPKeyExchangeFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaoaepkeyexchangeformatter.aspx) if you have the flexibility to support PKCS#1v2

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading how SSL or OpenPGP are implemented.

I'm not sure what part you are struggling with.

In short, the asymmetric algorithm is used for symmetric key exchange.

The symmetric algorithm is used for the bulk data (stream/block) crypto. You won't get it done with simply modifying your 2 functions, you will need to implement a handshake and key exchange.

Since you have an MVC.NET app, you can host it within a web server and gain HTTPS/SSL transport. You can also do the same with WCF. Any reason why aren't using what is provided by the underlying transport? You can even configure your application (web.config) to require client certificates.

PS: I agree about not re-inventing the wheel, even Microsoft's article that Erik linked to provides a warning about it.

> Caution We recommend that you do not attempt to create your own key exchange method from the basic functionality provided, because many details of the operation must be performed carefully in order for the key exchange to be successful.